# How can I print from Vim to PDF?

Tags: printing, pdf, vim

I would have thought this is rather simple, but I don't get it done: I use gVim and would like to get the text as a PDF file. In other applications like Firefox the print dialog shows me available printers and I can choose to print directly to a PDF file. However, in Vim there is no such dialog and the file is just sent to the standard printer of the system.

I tried the following:

- I'm not able to make the "print-to-pdf" thing my standard way of printing via the printer window of Ubuntu.
- `:ha > file` converts my file to a .ps file. That's nice, but .pdf would be nicer...

Answer (score 27):

Vim will not show you the print dialog box. Instead, you can print to a [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) file, open it in a PostScript viewer and print from there.

To print to a PostScript file from Vim:

```
:hardcopy > myfile.ps
```

You can also convert PostScript to PDF using `ps2pdf`:

```
ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

Comment: The first proposal means just changing the file extension...
The second one might work in a mapping or something like that, I will have to do some more research to get that done... Thanks so far...

Comment: It is as easy as changing an extension ;)

Comment: This is awesome, definitely didn't know this was a thing!
Can you get multiple files into a single document?

Comment: (cygwin user) `:ha > file.pdf` did not create a valid pdf file. Combining it with `ps2dpf` did work but gives me white background. I'm happiest with `:TOhtml file.html` and then printing this html file to pdf

Comment: I used a variation of this command today: :1,50 hardcopy, it didn't create a file, just printed from lines 1 to 50.

Comment: Additionally, to change the rendered font, I found I could do the following prior to the hardcopy command (to select Courier 8): 
`:set printerfont=Courier:h8`

Comment: neovim 0.9 removes to the :hardcopy option. Users are advised use :TOhtml instead.

Answer (score 15):

Building on what others have already stated:

You can use the following single-line Vim command to create a PDF file:

```
:hardcopy > %.ps | !ps2pdf %.ps && rm %.ps
```

Note:

- The `%` is shorthand for the current filename, so `HelloWorld.C` will print to `HelloWorld.C.pdf`
- If you want to also retain the intermediate .ps file, simply omit the `&& rm %.ps`, obtaining:
  `:hardcopy > %.ps | !ps2pdf %.ps`

Additionally, to change the rendered font, set the `printfont` *before* executing the `hardcopy` command.  For example, to select Courier 8:

```
:set printfont=Courier:h8
```

Putting it all together, I decided to add the following to my `.vimrc` file so that I can simply execute the `:HardcopyPdf` command. This command can also operate on a selected range within a file:

```
" Select the font for the hardcopy
set printfont=Courier:h8
command! -range=% HardcopyPdf <line1>,<line2> hardcopy > %.ps | !ps2pdf %.ps && rm %.ps && echo 'Created: %.pdf'
```

Comment: That is very neat Mathias, thanks. The range thing didn't work for me. I highlighted a range (using v) and the command acted on the whole file and ignored the range.

Comment: Do fonts other than Courier ever work?